# how to set remote logon session validate time

Tags: windows

When I have logged into a remote operating system, I always open a lot of documents. For example: word or excel. When I log off the remote system, then later log in again the documents are all closed!

How could I still make them in the status of last time i opened. Or how do I set the validate time of a remote session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about Terminal Services? On Windows Server, or Windows Professional? Are you actually clicking "Log Off", or are you just closing the remote session?

If you are actually logging off by clicking the "Log Off" button, this deliberately ends your session, so there's nothing you can do in this situation. But if you're just hitting the "close" button, then this puts your session into the "Disconnected" state, and there *are* ways of changing those sessions.

If you are talking about Windows Server, you will find the options under `Session Host Configuration` (It might be Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration if you're on 2008 or 2008 R2, or Terminal Services Session Host Configuration if you're on 2003).

If you open that menu item, you'll see something that looks like this:

[image]

Go to the Sessions tab, and you'll see all the settings you need:

[image]